# SSL or TLS when sending email

Tags: java, apache-commons-email

I want to send email from my java application, through my gmail account. I'm using apache-commons-email 1.4.
I have following code

```
HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail();
email.setHostName(hostName);
email.setSmtpPort(port);
email.setAuthenticator(defaultAutenticator);
email.setSSLOnConnect(true);
//email.setStartTLSEnabled(true);
//email.setStartTLSRequired(true);
email.setFrom(from);
email.setSubject(title);
email.setHtmlMsg(htmlContent);
email.setTextMsg(textContent);
email.addTo(recipient);
email.send();
```

This code works ok. My question is: What better to use SSL or TLS? Can I use them together?

As I understand from web search they are almost the same but SSL start encryption automatically on start of connection and TLS is not. So does it mean that SSL more secure?

Comment: Do you have control over the server?

Comment: No, only setting from gmail page